# Using gitignore to separate development and production environments

Tags: python, git, discord.py

So I'm working on learning python with the discord.py library and playing with bots. The bots require an API token, and I would like to separate the functional bot on the server, from the test bot I'm working on.

My environment would be set up with a master branch, and a dev branch. I'd like the master branch's code base to work with `Test Bot`, and the development branch's code base to work with `Test Bot Dev`. My idea was to have an API Token variable stored in an untracked file, and place that file on the server. Then have a local file on my PC that has the same file, but with a different token set as the variable.

It feels a little bit hacky though. I'm just wondering if there is a better standard practice for situations where you want to use one repository for your code base, but need to have a specific variable differ for your dev and prod environments. It's sort of a convoluted question, so I'm struggling to have much success in finding suggestions for this situation through searches.

Comment: Environment variables are likely your best option. You could have a single env var such as `"ENVIRONMENT=dev"`; upon startup you can add logic to pick up the right token based on the variable: `token = {'dev': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'test': 'eefdfsd'}[os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']]`.

Comment: Awesome, I just looked into them and they are extremely useful. Got it up and running. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the application with a the required profile under configuration management (git) and ignore any (local) overriding file.

For example, put a file named `.env.dist` under version control, while the file `.env` is in the `.gitignore` file of the same project (in that same path):

```
# dot env
/.env
```

Make your utility/bot load any `.env.dist` file by default and `.env` file overriding that `.env.dist` file. This allows you to document, plan and define required environment variables while allowing a user to keep a local copy with all the production credentials (if needed).

Then give your bot another parameter to load a different name environment (dot env) file taking the lead. This allows you to run the bot with any different configuration.

If you follow the syntax of environment files as used by the [Docker CLI utility](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file), you are most likely pretty inter-operable and can reach far by so w/o giving up much of your freedoms.

So take this as a suggestion.

Another one: If you would like to use diff-utilities to quickly compare between environment files, one tip I can provide is that if you create sections (as otherwise you should order the environment parameter (variable) names by name), give each section a header with (if not on top of the file) an empty line, a singe `#` comment, another comment with the section name `# name of section` and another single `#` line. This gives text-base diff tools enough food to keep sections apart of each other (and apart from other single-line comments).

```
#
# DISCORD API
#
DISCORD_ID
DISCORD_KEY

#
# MYSQL DATABASE
#
MYSQL_HOST
MYSQL_PASS
MYSQL_PORT
MYSQL_USER
```

(exemplary `.env.dist` file hinting required parameter while not providing any secrets)

```
#
# DISCORD API
#
DISCORD_ID=42
DISCORD_KEY=aefdcd8d71d200efaefdcd8d71d200ef


#
# MYSQL DATABASE
#
MYSQL_HOST=example.com
MYSQL_PASS=root
MYSQL_PORT=34732
MYSQL_USER=root
```

(exemplary `.env` file containing secrets and excluded (do not add!) via `.gitinore` in the git project directly).

Add more "dot env" files into `.git/info/exclude` and/or if you adopt this pattern to your whole development system into your *global `.gitignore`*. Read the description in the [Git gignore Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) how the (multilevel) gitignore is used and when it does not ignore any of the files even if specified.

Comment: Thanks so much. After the first response suggested environment variables, I read up on them and have them implemented so that my code searches the OS for a token. This will let me set up the token on the server, and whenever I run the code base locally, it will boot up the development bot. I think these are fairly similar solutions? Only you're using a file structure which differs. Are there advantages to doing it your way vs. how I've set it up?

Comment: If you have a single parameter, starting wit a single environment variable sounds fine to me. However as such environment variables then become more and more important, how to document which environment variables are to be used, e.g. when running on a different system. Making use of dot env files with a standard approach can help here. It's fully compatible with environment only approach and it's easy to load from dot env files into the environment as well so that this can be kept out of the concrete utility.